# Drawing on HTML5 Canvas with support for multitouch pinch, pan, and zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, multi-touch

I appreciate this is not strictly a code question - but I've not quite got to that point - let me explain...

I have a requirement to enable a user to draw (as simple freehand lines) onto an large image - and be able to zoom, pan and pinch (on an iPad).

This is driving me a bit crazy. I've looked at so many libraries, code samples, products etc and there seems to be nothing out there that meets this requirement i.e. drawing (one touch) WITH (multi-touch) pinch, zoom, pan. Lots of paint.net, signature captures etc, but nothing that supports the multi-touch bit.

I have tried to adapt various libraries to acheive what I want (e.g. combining an old version of [sketch.js](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Canvas-Based-Drawing-Plugin-with-jQuery-Sketch/) with [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io)) but to be honest I've struggled. I do suspect that I will have to write my own at the end of the day and use something like hammer.js (excellent by the way) for gestures.

Anyway just in case someone out there has come across a library that might fit my needs or can point me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

Feel free to give me a hard time for avoiding coding it myself ;-)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I appreciate this but I am a developer with a real programming problem. I have started coding a solution for the requirement but realised this is a significant challenge unless I can identify a suitable library. Other developers may well have been in this position. I described my approach of combining sketch.js and hammer.js which is a technical solution. I'm not asking 'Which is the best X or Y' which I understand is a real issue for you. If Stackoverflow is not the right forum for this - can you suggest one that is please?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Stack Overflow is a place for questions that can be answered objectively, which doesn't seem to be the case. I think your question would be more suitable if you reworded it to talk about your difficulties with combining sketch.js and hammer.js, or about the problems you faced when trying to write your own implementation of your idea. The only place I can think of for your question as it stands now is reddit, but I don't know any specific communities there that your question would fit.

Comment: OK fair enough I take your point. It is a shame however that developers cannot ask such questions without rebuke. I guess I will have to continue on my own without input from this community.

Comment: I agree, but I think it's for the best. A platform that thrives on a robust voting system isn't very suitable for opinionated answers, as people are gonna use it to bury the ones they don't particularly agree with. It happens often on reddit and it's one of the reasons that place isn't suitable at all for meaningful discussion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Custom touch.

The example shows custom one touch draw and 2point pinch scale, rotate, pan using the standard browser touch events.

You need to prevent the standard gestures via the CSS rule `touch-action: none;` on the body of the document or it will not work.

#### Pointer

The pointer object which is initialised with

```
const pointer = setupPointingDevice(canvas);
```

Handles the touch. Use `pointer.count` to see how many touches there are, the first touch point is available as `pointer.x`, `pointer.y`. An array of touch points can be accessed as `pointer.points[touchNumber]`

#### View

The is an object at the bottom that handles the view. Its just a 2D matrix with some additional functions to handle the pinch. `view.setPinch(point,point)` starts the pinch with the 2 points as the reference. then `view.movePinch(point,point)` for updates

The view is used to draw the `drawing` canvas on the display canvas. To get the world (drawing coordinates) you need to convert from touch screen coordinates (canvas pixels) to the transformed drawing. Use `view.toWorld(pointer.points[0]);` to get the coordinates of the pinched drawing.

To set the main canvas transform use `view.apply();`

#### Not perfect

Humans tend to be sloppy and the interface to the touch zoom needs to delay drawing a little bit as the 2 touches for a pinch action may not happen at once. When a single touch is detected the app starts recording drawing points. If after several frames there is no second touch then it locks into drawing mode. No touch events are lost.

If a second touch occurs within several frames of the first it is assumed that a pinch action is being used. The app dumps any previous drawing points and set the mode to pinch.

When the app is in draw or pinch mode they are lock until no touches are detected. This is to prevent unwanted behaviour due to sloppy touching.

#### Demo

The demo is meant only as an example.

**NOTE** this will not function for non touch devices. I throw a error is no touch is found.

**NOTE** I have done only the most basic of agent detection. Android, and iPhones, iPads, and anything that reports multi touch.

**NOTE** Pinch events often result in two points dragging into one. This example does not handle such event correctly. You should switch to pan mode when a pinch gesture becomes a single touch and turn of rotate and scale.

```js
    const U = undefined; 
    const doFor = (count, callback) => {var i = 0; while (i < count && callback(i ++) !== true ); };
    const drawModeDelay = 8; // number of frames to delay drawing just incase the pinch touch is
                             // slow on the second finger
    const worldPoint = {x : 0, y : 0}; // worldf point is in the coordinates system of the drawing
    
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var drawMode = false;    // true while drawing
    var pinchMode = false;   // true while pinching
    var startup = true;  // will call init when true
    
    // the drawing image
    const drawing = document.createElement("canvas");
    const W = drawing.width = 512;
    const H = drawing.height = 512;
    const dCtx = drawing.getContext("2d");
    dCtx.fillStyle = "white";
    dCtx.fillRect(0,0,W,H);
    
    // pointer is the interface to the touch
    const pointer = setupPointingDevice(canvas);
    ctx.font = "16px arial.";
    if(pointer === undefined){
      ctx.font = "16px arial.";
      ctx.fillText("Did not detect pointing device. Demo terminated.", 20,20);
      throw new Error("App Error : No touch found");

    }
    
    // drawing functions and data
    const drawnPoints = [];  // array of draw points
    function drawOnDrawing(){  // draw all points on drawingPoint array
      dCtx.fillStyle = "black";
        while(drawnPoints.length > 0){
            const point = drawnPoints.shift();
            dCtx.beginPath();
            dCtx.arc(point.x,point.y,8,0,Math.PI * 2);
            dCtx.fill();
            dCtx.stroke();
        }
    }
    // called once at start
    function init(){
      startup = false;
      view.setContext(ctx);
    }
    // standard vars
    var w = canvas.width;
    var h = canvas.height;
    var cw = w / 2;  // center 
    var ch = h / 2;
    var globalTime;



    // main update function
    function update(timer){
        if(startup){ init() };
        globalTime = timer;
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        if(w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight){
            cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
            ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
        }
        // clear main canvas and draw the draw image with shadows and make it look nice
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
        view.apply();
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.4;
        ctx.fillRect(5,H,W-5,5)
        ctx.fillRect(W,5,5,H);
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        ctx.drawImage(drawing,0,0);
        ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);  
        // handle touch.
        // If single point then draw
        if((pointer.count === 1 || drawMode) && ! pinchMode){
            if(pointer.count === 0){
                drawMode = false;
                drawOnDrawing();
            }else{
                view.toWorld(pointer,worldPoint);
                drawnPoints.push({x : worldPoint.x, y : worldPoint.y})
                if(drawMode){
                    drawOnDrawing();
                }else if(drawnPoints.length > drawModeDelay){
                    drawMode = true;
                }
            }
        // if two point then pinch.
        }else if(pointer.count === 2 || pinchMode){
            drawnPoints.length = 0; // dump any draw points
            if(pointer.count === 0){
                pinchMode = false;
            }else if(!pinchMode && pointer.count === 2){
                pinchMode = true;
                view.setPinch(pointer.points[0],pointer.points[1]);         
            }else{
                view.movePinch(pointer.points[0],pointer.points[1]);
            }       
        }else{
            pinchMode = false;
            drawMode = false;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);


    function touch(element){
        const touch = {
            points : [],
            x : 0, y : 0,
            //isTouch : true, // use to determine the IO type.
            count : 0,
            w : 0, rx : 0, ry : 0,
  
        }
        var m = touch;
        var t = touch.points;
        function newTouch () { for(var j = 0; j < m.pCount; j ++) { if (t[j].id === -1) { return t[j] } } }
        function getTouch(id) { for(var j = 0; j < m.pCount; j ++) { if (t[j].id === id) { return t[j] } } }

        function setTouch(touchPoint,point,start,down){
            if(touchPoint === undefined){ return }
            if(start) {
                touchPoint.oy = point.pageX;
                touchPoint.ox = point.pageY;
                touchPoint.id = point.identifier;
            } else {
                touchPoint.ox = touchPoint.x;
                touchPoint.oy = touchPoint.y;
            }
            touchPoint.x = point.pageX;
            touchPoint.y = point.pageY;
            touchPoint.down = down;
            if(!down) { touchPoint.id = -1 }
        }
    function mouseEmulator(){ 
        var tCount = 0;
        for(var j = 0; j < m.pCount; j ++){
            if(t[j].id !== -1){
                if(tCount === 0){
                    m.x = t[j].x;
                    m.y = t[j].y;
                }
                tCount += 1;
            }
        }
        m.count= tCount;
    }  
        function touchEvent(e){
            var i, p;
            p = e.changedTouches;
            if (e.type === "touchstart") {
                for (i = 0; i < p.length; i ++) { setTouch(newTouch(), p[i], true, true) }
            } else if (e.type === "touchmove") {
                for (i = 0; i < p.length; i ++) { setTouch(getTouch(p[i].identifier), p[i], false, true) }
            } else if (e.type === "touchend") {
                for (i = 0; i < p.length; i ++) { setTouch(getTouch(p[i].identifier), p[i], false, false) }
            }
            mouseEmulator();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        touch.pCount = navigator.maxTouchPoints;
        element = element === undefined ? document : element;
        doFor(navigator.maxTouchPoints, () => touch.points.push({x : 0, y : 0, dx : 0, dy : 0, down : false, id : -1}));
        ["touchstart","touchmove","touchend"].forEach(name => element.addEventListener(name, touchEvent) );
        return touch;
    }
    function setupPointingDevice(element){ 
        if(navigator.maxTouchPoints === undefined){ 
            if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Android") > -1  ||
                navigator.appVersion.indexOf("iPhone") > -1 ||
                navigator.appVersion.indexOf("iPad") > -1 ){
                navigator.maxTouchPoints = 5;
            }
        }
        if(navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0){
            return touch(element);
        }else{
            //return mouse(); // does not take an element defaults to the page.
        }
    }

    const view = (()=>{
        const matrix = [1,0,0,1,0,0]; // current view transform
        const invMatrix = [1,0,0,1,0,0]; // current inverse view transform
        var m = matrix;  // alias
        var im = invMatrix; // alias
        var scale = 1;   // current scale
        var rotate = 0;
        var maxScale = 1;
        const pinch1 = {x :0, y : 0}; // holds the pinch origin used to pan zoom and rotate with two touch points
        const pinch1R = {x :0, y : 0};
        var pinchDist = 0;
        var pinchScale = 1;
        var pinchAngle = 0;
        var pinchStartAngle = 0;
        const workPoint1 = {x :0, y : 0};
        const workPoint2 = {x :0, y : 0};
        const wp1 = workPoint1; // alias
        const wp2 = workPoint2; // alias
        var ctx;
        const pos = {x : 0,y : 0};      // current position of origin
        var dirty = true;
        const API = {
            canvasDefault () { ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) },
            apply(){ if(dirty){ this.update() } ctx.setTransform(m[0], m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4], m[5]) },
            reset() {
                scale = 1;
                rotate = 0;
                pos.x = 0;
                pos.y = 0;
                dirty = true;
            },
            matrix,
            invMatrix,
            update () {
                dirty = false;
                m[3] = m[0] = Math.cos(rotate) * scale;
                m[2] = -(m[1] = Math.sin(rotate) * scale);
                m[4] = pos.x;
                m[5] = pos.y;
                this.invScale = 1 / scale;
                var cross = m[0] * m[3] - m[1] * m[2];
                im[0] =  m[3] / cross;
                im[1] = -m[1] / cross;
                im[2] = -m[2] / cross;
                im[3] =  m[0] / cross;
            },
            toWorld (from,point = {}) {  // convert screen to world coords
                var xx, yy;
                if (dirty) { this.update() }
                xx = from.x - m[4];
                yy = from.y - m[5];
                point.x = xx * im[0] + yy * im[2];
                point.y = xx * im[1] + yy * im[3];
                return point;
            },
            toScreen (from,point = {}) {  // convert world coords to screen coords
                if (dirty) { this.update() }
                point.x =  from.x * m[0] + from.y * m[2] + m[4];
                point.y = from.x * m[1] + from.y * m[3] + m[5];
                return point;
            },
            setPinch(p1,p2){ // for pinch zoom rotate pan set start of pinch screen coords
                if (dirty) { this.update() }
                pinch1.x = p1.x;
                pinch1.y = p1.y;
                var x = (p2.x - pinch1.x);
                var y = (p2.y - pinch1.y);
                pinchDist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
                pinchStartAngle = Math.atan2(y, x);
                pinchScale = scale;
                pinchAngle = rotate;
                this.toWorld(pinch1, pinch1R)
            },
            movePinch(p1,p2,dontRotate){
                if (dirty) { this.update() }
                var x = (p2.x - p1.x);
                var y = (p2.y - p1.y);
                var pDist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
                scale = pinchScale * (pDist / pinchDist);
                if(!dontRotate){
                    var ang = Math.atan2(y, x);
                    rotate = pinchAngle + (ang - pinchStartAngle);
                }
                this.update();
                pos.x = p1.x - pinch1R.x * m[0] - pinch1R.y * m[2];
                pos.y = p1.y - pinch1R.x * m[1] - pinch1R.y * m[3];
                dirty = true;
            },
            setContext (context) {ctx = context; dirty = true },
        };
        return API;
    })();
```

```css
canvas  {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0px;
    left : 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}
body {
    background:#bbb;
    touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Blindman 67 - fantastic job that's exactly what I was looking for. Well pretty much (will create lines between points and add functions to change brush size/colour etc). Will post when done. Thanks again.